# Free YouTube desktop app for OS X with account support

Tags: gratis, osx, desktop-client, youtube

I would want to have access to my account's videos from some desktop app on OS X 10.9.3 (Mavericks). It would be great if the app is free.

The reason is that I don't want to be logged in with my Google account on the web browser all the time.

Comment: Access to my account's videos from some desktop app -> offline? without the need to log into your Google account?

Comment: What's this got to do with ios?

Comment: (sorry, meant osx)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Yep, I forgot to mention that it's the web browser that I don't want to have my account logged in all the time to watch my videos, I updated the question for clarification